# How to use same theme(Porto) for different website(multiwebsites) with different style

Tags: magento2, theme, multi-website

I want to use the same theme(Porto Theme) for different websites (multi websites) with different styles on a single Magento installation.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new theme that is a child of porto theme, assign it to your new website then change what you need in this child theme.

There you can find information on how to create a new theme with a specific parent theme : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html